# How to create a circle div with multiple links inside

Tags: html, css

I have a circle with multiple layers. My idea is to make them all individual links. For example if you clicked on the outer ring you'd be referred to page1 , the inner ring to page 2 and the one inside that to page 3. But I have no idea where to start, do any of you have an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I've found an article about Image map, where you can give links to the multiple circles.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create 3 divs, all with the following css properties:

```
position: absolute
border-radius: 100% #gives you that circle
```

Position them accordingly on top of one another, with `top: 10px; left: 10px` etc, then size them according to your `width` and `height` properties.

Manage which one goes on top via the `z-index` property in css as well.

Make them all anchor tags.

Here is an example, these are divs though.

[Click Me and Enjoy](http://jsfiddle.net/HpG3L/)